# Ruby script process monitoring on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, process-monitoring

I want to monitor my ruby script process remotely on windows. I do know how to do it on unix based system, with god or similar monitoring framework, but the issue is that I want to have it for windows.

Basically, I want to do a couple of things:

- Monitor whether the script is running
- If the script stops, it should be restarted
- Send the status of the script to remote server (This is not so important, I can write this option myself)

Maybe someone can suggest it.

Please note that I would prefer to have the monitoring solution written in ruby, so I could expand it further.

Comment: Have you looked at the ChildProcess gem? It works on Windows.  https://github.com/jarib/childprocess

Comment: @Threeve I will check it out and let you know if it works out. I have read somewhere that bluepill works on Windows, but have to test it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this on the forum [www.ruby-forum.com](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/68910) and adapted it a bit you that you can see if the process (script) still runs. Restarting and reporting you can handle yourself i presume ?

```
require 'WIN32OLE'

procs = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts:\\\\.")
procs.InstancesOf("win32_process").each do |p|
  puts p.commandline if p.name == 'ruby.exe'
end
```

Here the available attributes

```
class Win32_Process : CIM_Process
{
  string Caption;
  string CommandLine;
  string CreationClassName;
  datetime CreationDate;
  string CSCreationClassName;
  string CSName;
  string Description;
  string ExecutablePath;
  uint16 ExecutionState;
  string Handle;
  uint32 HandleCount;
  datetime InstallDate;
  uint64 KernelModeTime;
  uint32 MaximumWorkingSetSize;
  uint32 MinimumWorkingSetSize;
  string Name;
  string OSCreationClassName;
  string OSName;
  uint64 OtherOperationCount;
  uint64 OtherTransferCount;
  uint32 PageFaults;
  uint32 PageFileUsage;
  uint32 ParentProcessId;
  uint32 PeakPageFileUsage;
  uint64 PeakVirtualSize;
  uint32 PeakWorkingSetSize;
  uint32 Priority;
  uint64 PrivatePageCount;
  uint32 ProcessId;
  uint32 QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
  uint32 QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
  uint32 QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
  uint32 QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
  uint64 ReadOperationCount;
  uint64 ReadTransferCount;
  uint32 SessionId;
  string Status;
  datetime TerminationDate;
  uint32 ThreadCount;
  uint64 UserModeTime;
  uint64 VirtualSize;
  string WindowsVersion;
  uint64 WorkingSetSize;
  uint64 WriteOperationCount;
  uint64 WriteTransferCount;
};
```